# How does submitting work in php?

Tags: php, post

I am trying to learn php but there is one thing I don't understand how that works: POST.

With the tutorial I made a word censoring program so I have a form with a `textarea` and a `button` and some php code to handle it like you can see in the code below.

The part that I don't understand is where is the click event in the php to detect a button click or something like you have in Jquery.
Why don't you have something like this:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    //action in here
})
```

So can somebody help me to understand php `POST`.

**edit one:** So why don't you need a click event or something to detect a button click and than run the code.

**note:** if you downvote the question explain how I can improve the question.

```
<?php

  $find = array('world','hello','dale');
  $replace = array('w***d','h***o','d**e');

  if(isset($_POST['user_input'])&&!empty($_POST['user_input'])){
      $user_input = $_POST['user_input'];
      $user_input_new = str_replace($find, $replace, $user_input);

      echo $user_input_new;
  }

?>

<form action="index.php" method="POST">
<textarea name="user_input" rows="4" cols="30"><?php echo $user_input ?></textarea><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: `can somebody help me to understand php POST` - what exactly is not clear?

Comment: @cel I made an edit in regards to your comment

Comment: $('button').click(function(){ ... Here there is no tag button

Comment: The click on the `button[type=submit]` triggers the POST request defined in the `<form>` tag.

Comment: <button>send</button>$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $( "form" ).submit();
});

Comment: @D4V1D But how does php know that I want to run that `if statement` and not an other `if statement` in the file

Comment: Your `if` statement checks for key `user_input` in your array `$_POST`. As you have just submitted one, the `if` statement is ran. What are you struggling with?

Comment: @D4V1D I am struggeling with the part that you don't need a click event. I Work a lot with Jquery and when I need a button press detected I use a click event so I am confused why you don't need that in php `post`.

Comment: Because the `input` button is in a `<form>` tag. So the request is triggered by the button itself. No need for `jQuery` event.

Comment: @D4V1D you don't understand what I mean. In Jquery you use a click event to detect a button click. My question was why does php post not need a click event to detect a submit button click in this case. I know you don't need `Jquery` for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no interaction with the user in php as php is purely server-side.

You make a POST request by submitting your form or by making an ajax call to the script you have specified. The web-server receives the request and passes it on to php with all the POST / GET parameters. The php script processes and when it is finished, all output gets sent back to where the request came from; your browser.

So there is no interaction with a php script when you make a POST request from your browser and there are no events to catch. There is just a script that gets called and that has access to the posted parameters.

Comment: But for example, you have to `if statements` and two `forms`. How does php know that if you press the submit button he needs to run the first `if statement` and not the second `if statement`?

Comment: @Vinc199789 If your 2 forms post to the same script (that is possible but not necessary), the only way to differentiate them is if there are parameters set in one form and not in the other. So you can check for `$_POST['parameter_unique_in_form_one']` to see if that specific form was submitted / posted. Or you submit to different scripts...

Comment: So if I understand it right. When you click `submit`, The browser sends a signal to the server with all the data that can be found inside the `form` where the `submit button` is. In this case php I only interessted in the `textarea` data. He runs the script and send back the output if there is an output.

Comment: @Vinc199789 That's about it.

Comment: thanks for your help. I hope I can continue the tutorials now.